# Migrating from one mail server software to hMailServer

Tags: email-server, kerio

I have one 'old' server which uses Kerio MailServer 6 and I am planning on migrating the mail accounts( around 50-60 accounts ) to my new one which is using hMailServer.
I have not as of yet found a conversion utility which I could use, so I am hoping someone will have any knowledge on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

imapsync is great (at least for users with linux/bsd boxes).

Of course you have to use some kind of password-list...

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple "IMAP drag" between the servers. Horde also has similar capabilities built into it and there are also IMAP-to-IMAP tools available as well.